# IE10 broke axWebBrowser control

Tags: c#, internet-explorer-10, axwebbrowser

I maintain the code for a private company's proprietary web browser that its employees use to conduct their work. The browser uses the axWebBrowser COM object rather than the .NET WebBrowser control. I just updated to IE10 to test the browser with the new version and the axWebBrowser events stopped firing. I know I'm most likely going to have to update the browser to the .NET control, but I was wondering if anyone knows why the axWebBrowser control stopped working.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are some compatibility issues with IE10 and legacy controls, there are patches available for this.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh869299(v=vs.85).aspx

Also refer ASP.NET 4 Breaking Changes http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes